# using JUnitCore together with Spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, junit4

I want to execute a test from a main-class. I have tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
    runner.run(TestClass.class);
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore.main(TestClass.class.getName());
}
```

However, this test is using the Spring-framework and the beans aren't loaded.
My test-class looks like this:

```
@NoDataSet
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/.../xxx-beans.xml", "/.../yyy-beans.xml",
                    "..." }, inheritLocations = false)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TestClass extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass() {
        // some config
    }

    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        // testsomething
    }
}
```

I am using a lot of beans and therefore I can't load the beans manually.

Is there another way to start this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently, my working directory was set to an incorrect location.

I now use it wit the following main-method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
    runner.run(TestClass.class);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
new JUnitCore().run(new SpringJUnit4ClassRunner(Test1.class));
```

or simply add

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) to TestClass
```

Comment: According to the [JUnitCore-documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html), we shoudn't use this method. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The class is missing a `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation. Without this annotation, even your build tool or IDE wouldn't be able to execute it correctly.

Comment: It was just an example. I have this annotation in my original code, where the test works in my IDE (not in the main-class).